# Giving an ios app a long title(name) - auto break

Tags: ios, naming

I would like to know how do I name my iOS app in such a way that it will auto break when its long.

This is how I would like the name to be displayed..for android it auto breaks, but not such with iOS version:

[image]

This is the problem I have regarding the app name. It shows "..." instead of breaking:

[image]

Comment: You can't. iOS only shows one short line of text for the app name under the icon.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. What would you suggest that I do?

Comment: Perhaps give it a short name?

Comment: That's your only option. It's only the Display Name you need to change to be shorter. You can keep the longer full name in iTunes Connect.

Comment: WOW thank you so much.... I've noted everything down.. How do I vote you up? :) ... Im new on Stack Overflow.. again thank you so much